# How to run task after build is created in jenkins through gradle script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle` script which includes a couple of tasks and one last task is as below. The last task will create a zip file and now I need to copy this into destination directory with the different zip file names. I tried couple of functions to accomplish this but the build is failing with different types of errors.

Task in `build.gradle`:

```
task createDBDeploy(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'copyToDbfiles') {
    System.out.println("Starts createDBDeploy");
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    zip64 true
    archiveName = "dbfiles.zip"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}")
    System.out.println("Destination directory :${buildDir}");
    from "${buildDir}/dbfiles"
}
```

After I ran the above task I need to run the below task. I need the above file `dbfiles.zip` to be copied into destination dir `"${buildDir}"` with different names called `abc.zip`, `def.zip`, `feg.zip`, `ijk.zip`.
Could you please help me with the task which does the above?

I tried by using `doLast` and `finalizedBy` functions but my Jenkins builds are failing. So I am not sure how to execute the above task after my build is created.

I tried the below ways or methods:

**1st method:** Added the below task in `gradle.build` and ran the jenkins job but build is failing.

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
    into file("$buildDir/abc.zip") 
    from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
    into file("$buildDir/def.zip")
    from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
    into file("$buildDir/feg.zip") 
    from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
    into file("$buildDir/ijk.zip")
}

build.dependsOn copyFiles
```

**2nd method:** Added the below task in gradle.build and ran the jenkins job but build is failing.

```
task renameArtifacts(type: Copy) { 
    from ('$buildDir/') include 'dbfiles.zip' 
    destinationDir file('$buildDir/abc.zip')
    from ('$buildDir/') include 'dbfiles.zip' 
    destinationDir file('$buildDir/def.zip')
    from ('$buildDir/') include 'dbfiles.zip' 
    destinationDir file('$buildDir/feg.zip')
    from ('$buildDir/') include 'dbfiles.zip' 
    destinationDir file('$buildDir/ijk.zip')
}

build.dependsOn renameArtifcats
```

**3rd method:** Added the below task in gradle.build and ran the jenkins job but build is failing.

```
task finalize {
    doLast {
        from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
        into file("$buildDir/abc.zip") 
        from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
        into file("$buildDir/def.zip")
        from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
        into file("$buildDir/feg.zip") 
        from file("$buildDir/dbfiles.zip")
        into file("$buildDir/ijk.zip")
    }
}

build.finalizedBy finalize
```

After I tried all the ways I am getting the error while running build when I ran the above steps.

**Jenkins error log:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
22:34:54  
22:34:54  * Where:
22:34:54  Build file '/apps/jenkins_slave/workspace/proj/mod1/build.gradle' line: 292
22:34:54  
22:34:54  * What went wrong:
22:34:54  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mod1'.
22:34:54  > Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'mod1' of  type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: The broken formatting makes your question hard to read. I am sure improving it will make it more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: Hi Vester,Updated the question in a right format which could be understandable now.Thank you so much for your inputs. Could someone help on this please ?

Comment: the error says line 292, what is line 292?

Comment: Line 22 has the following line: build.dependsOn renameArtifcats in build.gradle file

Comment: @PRAVEEN  did you get a chance to try out my answer? Just want to make sure the bounty won't be lost :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you’d like to copy the same ZIP file to four new files? The following `Copy` task implementation should do that (tested with Gradle 6.7.1):

```groovy
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    into buildDir
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'abc.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'def.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'feg.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'ijk.zip'
    }
}
```

Or more concisely:

```groovy
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    into buildDir
    ['abc', 'def', 'feg', 'ijk'].each { name ->
        from(buildDir) {
          include 'dbfiles.zip'
          rename 'dbfiles.zip', "${name}.zip"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you chriki. I will check and let you know. Thank you so much.

Comment: I want the above task to run only after DB deploy task so how to add depends on section for the above task which you provided.When I run from jenkins its not picking up the above section due to no depends on relation with the above section.Kindly update the depends on section for the above task

Comment: Tried the below task but no luck.                                                                                  
  task copyFiles(type: Copy, dependsOn:'createDBDeployOrg' ) {
   into buildDir
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'abc.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'def.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'feg.zip'
    }
    from(buildDir) {
      include 'dbfiles.zip'
      rename 'dbfiles.zip', 'ijk.zip'
    }
}

Comment: Assuming that the `createDBDeployOrg` task creates the `$buildDir/dbfiles.zip` file, your dependency declaration should work. It’s hard to say what could be wrong without more information.